# Need Text Box mode password only in cruise control.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am working on CruiseControl.Net. I am using textbox like below code

```
<parameters>

<textParameter>
        <name>Password</name>
        <display>No</display>
        <description>Enter Password?</description>
        <default>pass@12345</default>
        <required>false</required>

    </textParameter>
```

but problem is that when I am going to type anything, it's visible whatever I have entered in textbox. So I want my textbox should be password mode.

Answer (score 1):

this is issue 220 :
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/220

so not available yet